# Getting number of views for a document through JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: 2013, document-library

In SharePoint 2013,  it keeps number of views for a document.  It only appears when someone clicks on the (...) to see the document sub-menu.

Does anyone knows if there is a way to read this information through JavaScript (or web service call).  I would like to use this information.

[image: Number of Views]

Answer (score 2):

It is available through search API, use the ViewsLifeTime property.

Comment: Thanks Aveenav,  do you have any code samples for interacting with Search REST APis through JS?

Comment: Take a look at MSDN.